# headphone or earphone that can completely block any noise

Tags: headphones, wearable-technology, earphones

Are there any device that exist that can completely block any loud noise in public places? I intend to use it in public places (i.e. coffee shop, park, bar) so I can work with little or without any distraction. Noise can range from people talking, cars driving by to jackhammer that is used in a nearby construction. I've considered anti noise ear plugs, noise isolation earphones and noise cancelling headphones but just seem to just lessen the noise but not completely block it. Are there any viable solution that exist?

Comment: Completely block the sound of a jackhammer?  Have you considered building yourself an anechoic chamber?

Comment: Bose QuietComfort 35's should do the trick for the acoustic levels, but you're likely feeling the impact of the jackhammer as well as/rather than hearing it.

Comment: The jackhammer would be a rare occasion and might be the most extreme cases. I only mentioned it as a reference to what kind of noise will be considered. 

@spikey_richie will the noise cancelling feature also work to just isolate the background noise even when you're not listening to any audio?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe so, yes

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider custom-molded in-ears. As they’re precisely fitted for your ears alone, not only they block out noise more effectively, they can also be extremely comfortable.

If you’re okay with deep insertion in-ears, you could check out the Etymotic ER4 as well. Or, consider foam eartips for your earphones.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll find a review about them and see if this will suffice to what i'm looking for. Thank you1

Comment: @Pennf0lio I would suggest looking at JH Audio, Flipears, Lear, Rooth, ACS, and Westone. They do custom molded in-ears. They sound extremely good as well, better and more accurate than the Bose QuietComforts.